# Multiple keys to 1 key but values as sum

Tags: java

Obviously I have found another thread about this, but it is not helping me in any way.

My problem: the output does

1. not contain all license plates (only 5 out of 36 are in the output somehow, no idea how thats possible)
2. if it contains a license plate, it only contains the last one (which is probably because I didnt do the multiple keys stuff right)

As shown below, the problem is in the if statements. So what should the if statements do?

- if before = true, look at whether the nachtMap already contains a key that is equal to licenseplateList.get(i).
- If it does contain that already, then add the value (kmperlineList.get(i))  to the value of that key (so value + kmperlineList.get(i).
- If it does not contain that,  then just put the licenseplateList.get(i) as key, and add the value kmperlineList.get(i)

  - if before != true , look at whether after is true or not,
- if after is true, then still do it for the nachtMap (also if contains blahblah.., exact same)
- if after is not true, then do it for the dagMap (also if contains blahblah, exact same but then for dagMap)

For the entire code check:
https://pastebin.com/jaSTm1DR

```
if (before) {

    // does our map already contain this license?
    if (nachtMap.containsKey(licenseplateList.get(i))) {
        kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", ".");

        // then remove that one, add new one but have the sum of the values
        // is this extra ) after ".get(i)" correct?
        Double sum = nachtMap.remove(licenseplateList.get(i)) + Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i));
        nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), sum);
    }
    // if it doesnt contain the license yet, just put it in there
    else {
        kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", ".");
        nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i)));
    }
}
// if its not before 06:00
else {

    // als de tijd na 17:30 is
    if (after) {
        if (nachtMap.containsKey(licenseplateList.get(i))) {
            Double sum = nachtMap.remove(licenseplateList.get(i)) + Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i));
            nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), sum);
        } else {
            kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", ".");
            nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i)));
        }

    }
    // otherwise it's always day
    else {

        // again: does the map already contain this license plate?
        if (dagMap.containsKey(licenseplateList.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("works");// debug
            kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", ".");

            // then get the sum of the values, but only 1 time the key
            Double sum = dagMap.remove(licenseplateList.get(i)) + Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i));
            dagMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), sum);
        }

        // if the map does not contain the license plate
        else {

            kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", ".");
            dagMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), Double.parseDouble(kmperlineList.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you made sure that all your parsing yields 36 unique license plates instead of assuming you do?

Comment: Yes it is all in a for loop so its just reading it per line and per line its putting it in an arraylist, then it parses the value in the arraylist to LocalTime and then its looking at whether that localtime is before or after a certain time. If yes, then put the kilometers (which has index i of the forloop also) in nachtMap (translated NIGHTmap), otherwise DAYmap You feel me? (its about kilometers driven in day and night per license plate)

Comment: What is the purpose of those `replaceAll` calls? You *don't use the returned value*, so the **statements do nothing**.

Comment: The purpose of replaceAll is that my CSV file contains kilometers values of for example "261,8" and i suppose that it cannot count with comma's, only with dots

Comment: edit: the replaceAll calls are not needed, but are neither a problem (tested it) I just wrote it to be 100% sure that it wouldnt be able to count with it

Comment: anyone with an idea what it could be???

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, except that it is way too long. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Ehm I might know it.. Cuz ive written another version of this, i had to specify the Charset. And I think thats the problem again. Just dont know how to do this in this code.......... Files.lines(Paths.get("", filepath), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))

Comment: when i replace IN the file the commas for dots, it DOES work. But I want it to be replaced in th ecode (this does not work.) I think it has something to do with charset. Also, if i replace it in the file with dots the code is perfectly fine, BUT for some license plate it gives for example "12.666.999.999.999.900", while the right answer is 1266,7 I think it has something to do with the usage of doubles. Could you look at my code and tell me what causes it / how to fix it

Comment: @whateverrr So you apparently didn't understand my comment about `replaceAll`. The `replaceAll()` method doesn't update the value in-place (can't, since strings are immutable), it **returns** the updated value, and you *discard* the returned value!!! Since you don't use the returned value, the call to `replaceAll` **has no effect**, as I've already said ("statements do nothing").

Comment: yep that sounds very logic, as its still refering to where the list.get(i) is saved in memory. What I could do is to save let's String anyname = kmperlineList.get(i).replaceAll(",", "."); and then call anyname instead of list.get(i) . Right?

Comment: yep its working thanks. Only dont understand the 12.666.999.999.999.900 any idea on thaT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is overly complex and redundant.

But first, it seems your file is using non-US number formatting (`1000,00`, not `1000.00`), so you should use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with correct `Locale` to parse the number, instead of [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) which parses Java-syntax numbers.

Assuming Java 8 (since all earlier versions are end-of-life now), your code can be reduced to:

```
double kmperline = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY)
                               .parse(kmperlineList.get(i)).doubleValue();
Map<String, Double> mapToUpdate = (before || after ? nachtMap : dagMap);
mapToUpdate.merge(licenseplateList.get(i), kmperline, Double::sum);
```

Comment: @whateverrr *All* the code shown in the question is replaced by those 3 statements (52 lines reduced to 4 lines).

Comment: @whateverrr How could I guess at that without knowing that the value in the file is? If your file is not consistent on whether to use `.` or `,` for the decimal point, there is no way for code to read useful information from garbage.

Comment: @whateverrr No. Perhaps if you tried **debugging** the code, to see the values of `kmperline` vs `kmperlineList.get(i)`, you'll figure it out. We can't debug *your* code, because 1) that's not why we are here, and 2) we don't have enough information to do it, even if we wanted to.